# Javascript namespace explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain what this name spacing is doing?

```
app.framework.superNav = {};
(function (superNav, $) {
 // code
})(app.framework.superNav, jQuery);
```

Comment: You should tag this with jQuery as well.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question.  It's an IIFE/scope question

Comment: It's doing nothing except allowing you to use `superNav` to access `app.framework.superNav` variable and `$` for `jQuery` for your `// code`. How it is defined, you still could use the original variables inside, though (unless they are removed afterwards)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: _"Possible duplicate of What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript"_ no he isn't asking that.